# Right-click on datagrid cell to bring up copy menu (ContextMenu)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, contextmenu

I've been trying to create right click functionality to bring up a context menu in C# but it doesn't seem to be working. Any idea why?

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        ContextMenu m = new ContextMenu();
        m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Copy"));

        int currentMouseOverRow = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex;

        m.Show(dataGridView1, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're using, WPF/WinForms/BlackMagic/Etc... but it seems that every right click you'll be creating a NEW context menu, which isn't attached to anything...

```
ContextMenu MyMenu = new ContextMenu();
MyMenu.MenuItems.Add("Copy");
```

You should have that attached to whatever control you're using (in your case, the grid I suppose, or the row):

```
SomeGrid.ContextMenu = MyMenu;
```

In WPF, using one on a ListBox would look like

```
<ListBox x:Name="NameYourList"  
      ItemsSource="{Binding SomeItem}"
      SelectedItem="{Binding SomeProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
      >
<ListBox.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Header ="Copy Me" Command="{Binding Copy_Command}" 
                  CommandParameter="{Binding SomeProperty}"
        />
    </ContextMenu>
</ListBox.ContextMenu>
```

Comment: I'm creating a Windows Form Application

Comment: Did you try the first 2 bits of code? create the context menu once, and set it on your object?

Comment: `private void dataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            ContextMenu MyMenu = new ContextMenu();
            MyMenu.MenuItems.Add("Copy");
            dataGridView1.ContextMenu = MyMenu;
        }` < no luck with this

Comment: don't set the it in the mouse click event ... set it in the window ctor or a global place. If you do it inside the click, you are creating the menu only after the click happened. You want it created and set when the form loads.